# Unable to pass parameters from AJAX to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a "load more" function in my web app. It should be automatic, so, as soon as the page is fully loaded, it calls a PHP file to load the other products.

I'm calling the PHP file through AJAX as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var limit = 999999;

  $.ajax({
     url: "php/load_more.php",
     type: 'get',
     async: false,
     cache: false,
     data: {'limit': limit},
     success: function(response) {
        console.log("log");
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error: " + thrownError);
     }
  })
});
```

The problem is that when I try to get the "limit" variable in the backend, it returns null even though in the network tab I can see that it is correctly sent.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET);   // Prints: array(0) { }

?>
```

What am I missing?

I also tried to check if `isset($_GET["limit"])` was true, but it returned false.

Comment: `data: {limit: limit},`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, but it doesn't change anything. When I try to var_dump($_GET) it returns [], but in the success function in AJAX I can see the variable, don't know why

Comment: what is happening when you open the php url directly in the browser having the limit parameter as query string?

Comment: @Daxcode The parameter is correctly printed in that case. The problem is that I don't want parameters in my url, I just want to send it through AJAX.

Comment: @giovanni13696 GET does not support any data in the body (refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Once you change the method type to POST or PUT or provide the data in the URL it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The offset variable is responsible for the displacement (or index) of the first record you want to fetch from the database. This variable will increase by the value of limit each time the user requests more data. This allows for retrieving successive portions of data from the database.

```
var offset = 0;

success: function(response) {
    console.log("log");
    // Tutaj dodaj logikę do wyświetlania załadowanych produktów
    offset += limit; // Zwiększ wartość offsetu o limit
},
```

Using the offset variable in conjunction with limit makes AJAX requests more efficient. As a result, only the appropriate portions of data are fetched from the database, instead of loading all the data at once.

Comment: How should this answer help me? Where did I mention the database? The problem here is that the $_GET array in my backend is empty, even though the AJAX request sends the "limit" parameter.

Comment: I recreated your code locally. In the load_more.php file, I set echo json_encode($_GET); and in the AJAX call, after receiving the response from PHP, I checked the value of the response variable with console.log inside the success function:

javascript
Copy code
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log("log");
}
As a result, I got the value of the limit variable as 999999.

Comment: It's correct, I get the same result. The problem is that in the success function I get the variable, but printed on screen I get [] as result of echo json_encode($_GET). Can you tell me why? For this reason, I can't get the value in PHP, it is null if i try to echo json_encode($_GET["limit"])